# Application error: My Flask-web-app is successfully deploy on Heroku but receiving application error when loading site

Tags: python, git, flask, heroku

the project structure is following

myapp is a root directory and it has the following files

1. Procfile
2. flask_app.py
3. requirements.txt
4. runtime.txt

1: Profile contains the following

```
web: gunicorn app:app
```

2: flask_app.py contain the following code

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'Welcome to my web '

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

3: runtime.txt contain

```
python-3.8.3
```

4: requirements.txt contain

```
click==7.1.2
Flask==1.1.2
gunicorn==20.0.4
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.11.2
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
Werkzeug==1.0.1
```

Executing these command

```sh
$ heroku login

$ git init 

$ heroku git:remote -a appname

$ git add.

$ git commit -am "make it better"

$ git push heroku master
```

after executing  the last command
when I am clicking  on the link it gives me the following error

Application error

An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details. You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command
Heroku logs --tail

Comment: Is your app ok in local?

Comment: yes it working properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is some problem with Procfile. It should be

```
web: gunicorn wsgi:app
```